# Publish ImmutableList of type Interface

Tags: java, multithreading, immutability

I am working on a Problem, where a class holds a list which is read very often, but is written only once in a while. If I understood it correctly, the following class should be thread-safe assuming MyInterface is immutable:

```
public class MyClass{
    private volatile ImmutableList<MyInterface> list = ImmutableList.of();

    public List<MyInterface> get(){
       return list;
    }

    public synchronized add(MyInterface obj)
       list = ImmutableList.builder().addAll(list).add(obj).build();
    }
}
```

But it could fail, if the someone implements mutable and not thread-safe version of MyInterface. How can I solve this Problem. I could implement against a final class, but is this really best practise?

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like you are reimplementing a CopyOnWriteArrayList...

Comment: @assylias: I intended to give a simple example. In reality, MyClass has more members and functionality.

Comment: @ManuelSchmidt I agree with assylias.  You should be using a CopyOnWriteArrayList.  This will allow you to remove the synchronized on add because CopyOnWriteArrayList.add will handle that for you.  Next, you should not expose this list.  Instead of returning the list you should delegate these calls to the underlying list.  If you want to expose get() have that method just call the CopyOnWriteArrayList's get. You can do the same for iterators or anything else.  This also allows you to completely change the underlying data structure whenever you want

Comment: If any `MyInterface` implementation is mutable and non-thread-safe, there's absolutely nothing any list implementation could do.

Answer (score 0):

Using a synchronized method, the mutex used by the Thread is the "this" class (in this case, the MyClass instance). So only one thread at a time can add an item to your list, since the entire method is synchronized. That is not related to the MyInterface, which is only a parameter to the method in this case.

Comment: yes, but the get() method returns the entire List and the caller could for example call methods on the elements of the list. If MyInterface is mutable, the state of the list changes.

Comment: @ManuelSchmidt No, the state of the list doesn't change, the state of the content of the list does. You can't force implementations of an interface to be immutable anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The (im)mutability of the implementation of MyInterface has no effect on the ImmutableList itself. add() doesn't call any method on the object.

Comment: An object is only as immutable as its publicly accessible objects.  You are referring to an unmodifiable list, an immutable list requires all its content to be immutable.  For example, an unmodifiable list of String is also immutable, but if it were of java.util.Date it would not be immutable.

Comment: @JohnVint But that can't be enforced, and he's obviously using [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/ImmutableCollectionsExplained).

Answer (score -1):

First of all, you will need to make your get() method also synchronized in MyClass.

Further more there is nothing in the java syntax that can enforce immutability on a implementing class. Its a matter of creating good coding guidelines.

Comment: Why would get need to be synchronized?

Comment: @assylias because he is synchronizing on the add method as well and the list field is mutable. If you dont care about raceconditions in this code, its okay to omit it.

Comment: list is volatile so there is no race condition as is (reference assignment in the add method is atomic).